# Polish, Russian and Greek in one file

Tags: languages, unicode

Is there any way to use these three languages in one file? I've been trying to do this for several hours, and all I got are some cryptic errors. Could you provide me with a simplest possible working template, that would have some text in these three languages?

And I would like to use UTF-8 everywhere, if it's possible.

Comment: Are you writing a joke ? *One Greek, one Russian and one  Polish went to a bar....* :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed here is to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), provided the font you pick covers all of the glyphs required. For example, on my system

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\begin{document}
Cześć ludzie

привет мир

Γεια σας κόσμο
\end{document}
```

works fine with either of the two modern TeX engines.

Comment: Consider adding [polyglossia](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/polyglossia) to this if you want hyphenation, redifined document strings (“chapter”, “figure” etc) and more.

Comment: @Joseph, this looks fantastic -- but in my linux machine I get "Package fontspec Error: The font "Cambria" cannot be found."  Is there any Unversal-font that we could use in plataform-independent Lualatex?

Answer (score 6):

In "ordinary LaTeX" you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,russian,polish]{babel}

\begin{document}
Cześć ludzie

\foreignlanguage{russian}{привет мир}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{Γεια σας κόσμο}
\end{document}
```

This needs TeX Live 2012 (or an up-to-date MiKTeX); with older distributions, remove `LGRx` and use `utf8x` as option to `inputenc`.

With TeX Live 2011 at the latest version, one can use the same method, but due to an error in the packaging of files the following trick in the preamble is needed:

```
\makeatletter
\input{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lgrx/lgrenc.dfu}
\makeatother
```