# How can I make overleaf display many different sparsely used unicode characters

Tags: unicode, overleaf

I would like to use many different characters for my Latex document. I won't be writing in those languages, but using a character here and there. I can't seem to display them in overleaf. What should I do to display the characters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{test}
1: ნ
2: ؾ
3: ꓕ

\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Three errors are displayed (one for each character)

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ნ (U+10DC)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 1: ნ
          
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

Comment: did you see that you get three errors?

Comment: I did, any idea how to fix them?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code

Comment: The easiest is to select XeLaTeX (click on the Overleaf menu button in the top left and in the Compiler dropdown list choose XeLaTeX) and then find a font that has all the characters you need, for example DejaVu Serif. MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}
1: ნ
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Marijn ,  thanks. Now the Georgian character works. The Arabic and Fraser character however aren't. Do you happen to know of a font that has all unicode characters?

Comment: I realize that I can add fonts per line by writing {\fontspec{DejaVu Serif} ნ} . Do you know of a way of searching for Latex fonts based on the language?

Comment: a good starting point would be `polyglossia` package. It allows for the support of different languages.

Comment: @finks Font `Code2003` has a lot; it was for testing Unicode, so is a bit just basic design. There are >140k characters and increasing in Unicode, too many for one font file. Look at the Noto fonts on Google for many languages.

Comment: Thanks. `Code2003` covers a lot, but not enough. I think I will simply add images of the glyphs

Comment: Note that you can also make a pdf with LaTeX containing just the single character (with a font that covers that particular character and `\documentclass{standalone}`) and include those pdfs as images in your real document. This gives you better quality than bitmap-based image formats and also allows for searching, selecting, and copying from the final pdf.

Comment: Or of course use `fontspec` to load several different fonts for each character and select the appropriate font when you want to use that character. If you put this in a macro it can be easy to type. Alternatively you can setup 'fallback fonts' to automatically try different fonts if the main font does not contain a character, then you can just use the original characters in your document without any macros.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529663/unicode-multi-alphabet-dictionary/529679. See also https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combofont.

Comment: Thanks, that would still require me to find multiple fonts so that I can support all unicode. `Code2003` doesn't even have enough (eg. Egyptian hieroglyphs)

Comment: you will always need multiple fonts, it's not possible to have a single opentype font with every unicode character.