# Substitute font usage in XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, luacode

I have using `LuaLaTeX` and is there any way to tell XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to make automatic substitutions if the font is missing glyphs?

My LaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math,luacode} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times LT StdX}
\setsansfont{Helvetica LT Std}
\setmonofont{Helvetica LT Std}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\setmathrm{TimesLTStdX-Roman.otf}
\setmathfont[range={up}]{TimesLTStdX-Roman.otf}
\setmathfont[range={it}]{TimesLTStdX-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{TimesLTStdX-Roman.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin}]{TimesLTStdX-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont[range={bfup}]{Stix Two Math}
\setmathfont[range={bfit}]{Stix Two Math}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
           {18\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {\fontspec{Helvetica LT Std Bold}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
           {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {6\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
           {\fontspec{Helvetica LT Std}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\itshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{Cylindrical systems in general relativity}
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction\label{sec:1}}
\noindent{The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered a class of solutions of Einstein’s vacuum field equations, corresponding to static cylindrical spacetimes have been extensively investigated with various motivations.}
\subsection{Main properties of LT solutions with Λ > 0\label{sec:1_1}}
\noindent{The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered a class of solutions of Einstein’s vacuum field equations, corresponding to static cylindrical spacetimes have been extensively investigated with various motivations.}
\end{document}
```

So it would for example use one font as main and if something is missing would fall back to another substitute font or at least to a non-monospace font that has the correct glyphs?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529663/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How to do in `LuaLaTeX`? `\XeTeXinterchartoks` it will work in `LuaLaTeX`? or any other example?

Comment: the link I sent shows two lualatex examples.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have not seen. Okay. Thanks. Now i have need all the symbols like `Λ` is needed in `Free Serif` font. How to do in both cases like text and math(inline and display)...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have tried many more and not found the solutions. I have need missing glyphs should come alternative fonts(like STIX Two Math or Free Serif, or any).