# greek typeface different from the roman typeface in xelatex (automatically)

Tags: xetex, typefaces

I'm writing a document in several languages. I'm using NewComputerModern as main font and I want to keep it but I'd like to have the libertine typeface when I write in greek.

Is it possible to make it automatically, without having to use a specific command every time I write in greek ?

Comment: There are several options, but some of them require `luatex`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529663/unicode-multi-alphabet-dictionary .

Comment: I'm more inclined to recommend properly segregating language changes. However it depends on what material you need to print in, say, Greek: just single words or longer chunks of text?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a lot of long quotes in greek, that I put in the footnotes most of the times